# Streaming video capture on headless server

Tags: video-capture-card

I have a headless Ubuntu server, not running X, with a Kodicom 4400 clone video capture card installed(BT878 chips).  I tried setting up Zoneminder but I have been having trouble getting the cards to show up as a monitor.  I have since uninstalled Zoneminder and I am starting again from scratch.

Before I try installing Zoneminder again, I want to first be able to test that the card is set up properly and I can view video from one of the input channels.  Please assume my camera works, in case you ask.  Since X is not installed, I want to either capture to a file and view the capture files individually or perhaps more preferably, serve the video capture frames (i.e stream) and view them from a remote computer via TCP/IP.  I am trying to circumvent X, since none of the image data will ever need to go to the host's terminal.  If you think I am crazy, you are probably right; but I want to know what is actually going on.  I have the belief that the video data from a capture card does not need X to be extracted and served; only if detailed images are to be displayed on host does the host actually need X.

Here are my questions:

1. Without installing XAWTV or X, how can I configure my capture card so it is actually working correctly on my headless server?
2. What software and configuration will enable me to capture the frames from the capture card without the use of a GIU or installing X dependencies?
3. What software is available to stream (i.e. successively serve video frame images) the video frames from a capture card to a remote computer's browser?
4. Please do not be vague or simplistic; I will be able to understand detailed answers. I understand programming languages (I am an embedded software developer myself).  I will greatly appreciate being directed to the appropriate technical resources that will answer my questions.

I have had a couple of years using Zoneminder to handle a couple of cams in my back yard but my server's hard drive died recently and I am trying to get my system up again.  I thought that having X support really wasn't necessary and I am trying to understand the underlying processes.

Thanks in advance,

Allan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mencoder from the mplayer package to capture to a file from the command line.

mencoder −tv driver=v4l:width=640:height=480 tv:// −o tv.avi −ovc raw

There are a ton of options

mencoder -tv driver=v4l:width=640:height=480 tv:// -of mpeg -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg1video -oac copy -o output.mpg